# What's the purpose of SDL_opengl_glext.h?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I want to render some stuff using OpenGL 4.3 and SDL 2 on Windows 10 64 bit.
I know I have to load the function pointers at run time after context creation using a function loading library like GLEW or manually using SDL_GL_GetProcAddress.
But I noticed an header file **SDL_opengl_glext.h**.


After looking into it I found some function typedefs for example:

```
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC) (GLsizei n, GLuint *buffers);
```

But also some function prototypes for example:

```
GLAPI void APIENTRY glGenBuffers (GLsizei n, GLuint *buffers);
```

**Whats exactly the purpose of this function typedefs and prototypes? Why SDL include this header file?**

Answer (score 3):

Because SDL needs to talk to OpenGL too. So it's going to load OpenGL functions for its own needs. That header is really just a form of the standard OpenGL header `glext.h`.